# out a function which out's parameters

Tags: c#, delegates, out

I'm trying to make things easier for other developers by adding a response function right into the function they call. I can't really explain what I'm trying to achieve here, but I've seen it before, so I know it's possible.

What I want the result to be:

```
InventoryController.Instance.AddItemToInventory(0, 5, out (InventoryOperations operation) =>
{
    switch (operation)
    {
        case InventoryOperations.Success:
            Debug.Log("Successfully added the item!");
            break;
        case InventoryOperations.InventoryIsFull:
            Debug.Log("Inventory is full!");
            break;
    }
});
```

And the function they're calling is:

```
/// <summary>
/// Adds the item times the amount to the inventory.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="itemID">Item I.</param>
/// <param name="amount">Amount.</param>
public void AddItemToInventory(int itemID, int amount, out OnTaskComplete onTaskComplete)
{
    onTaskComplete = _onTaskComplete;

    //if we have the item, stack it
    if(itemsInInventory.ContainsKey(itemID))
    {
        //increment it
        itemsInInventory[itemID] += amount;
        //successfully return the operation
        _onTaskComplete(out InventoryOperations.Success);
    }
    else
    {
        if(itemsInInventory.Count < maxInventorySpaces)
        {
            itemsInInventory.Add(itemID, amount);
            _onTaskComplete(out InventoryOperations.Success);
        }
        else
        {
            _onTaskComplete(out InventoryOperations.InventoryIsFull);
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't work. I just tried to create a delegate and out the parameters, aswell as the delegate itself. But it didn't work.

Comment: This makes no sense whatsoever. `out` needs to be assigned somewhere, and I dont see that happening anywhere.

Comment: It is obvious that you can't really explain what you are trying to achieve here. Even if you can, we would not understand.

Comment: @leppie out is set in the first line in AddItemToInventory()

Comment: `out` is used for variables. not constants. i suggest you read http://www.dotnetperls.com/out https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee332485%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: @nick-peelman you cannot pass a constant as out parameter. Do this code compile? This line should'nt, or -5 to me. _onTaskComplete(out InventoryOperations.Success);

Comment: The first block of code is how i wanted it to be, more or less. this is, for example, a piece of code from a plugin in Unity, where I can handle the success of the executed function: http://imgur.com/0k1Z0nQ
But I have never programmed that before, and I have no idea how to google it :/

Comment: You don't appear to need to use `out` at all, so you should just be able to declare `onTaskComplete` as an `Action<InventoryOperations>`.

Comment: You don't seem to know what `out` does, follow the links you've been given. Though why not just keep it simple and return an `InventoryOperations` and avoid all this indirection?

Comment: Thanks lee, that did the trick! I'll add it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get where you want to go, you don't really need to use an out param. Just return the the value from the method:

```
    public InventoryOperations AddItemToInventory(int itemId, int amount)
```

Otherwise, just pass the function in (without the keyword):

```
InventoryController.Instance.AddItemToInventory(0, 5, (InventoryOperations operation) =>
{
    switch (operation)
    {
        // do something here
    }
});


public void AddItemToInventory(int itemID, int amount, Action<InventoryOperations> onTaskComplete)
{
    var result = do some business logic here;

    if(result == successful)
        onTaskComplete(InventoryOperations.Success);
    else
        onTaskComplete(InventoryOperations.InventoryIsFull);
}
```

Liberal psuedocode, but you should get the idea.

Comment: thanks to lee I already figured it out, but yours is as good as lee's answer :) + 1 and checked as the answer, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Lee, All I had to do is use

> System.Action

So the new code is:

```
InventoryController.Instance.AddItemToInventory(0, 5, (InventoryOperations operation) =>
                                                            {
                switch(operation)
                {
                case InventoryOperations.Success:
                    Debug.Log("Successfully added the item!");
                    break;
                case InventoryOperations.InventoryIsFull:
                    Debug.Log("Inventory is full!");
                    break;
                }
            });
```

And the function behind it is:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Adds the item times the amount to the inventory.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="itemID">Item I.</param>
        /// <param name="amount">Amount.</param>
        public void AddItemToInventory(int itemID, int amount, Action<InventoryOperations> OnComplete)
        {

            //if we have the item, stack it
            if(itemsInInventory.ContainsKey(itemID))
            {
                //increment it
                itemsInInventory[itemID] += amount;
                //successfully return the operation
                OnComplete(InventoryOperations.Success);
            }
            else
            {
                if(itemsInInventory.Count < maxInventorySpaces)
                {
                    itemsInInventory.Add(itemID, amount);
                    OnComplete(InventoryOperations.Success);
                }
                else
                {
                    OnComplete(InventoryOperations.InventoryIsFull);
                }
            }
        }
```